# Caesar Cipher repeats letters

Tags: c, cs50, caesar-cipher

Basically I have to create a caesar cipher, which is solely replacing each letter given with a letter that is int 'k' away. This takes 2 command line arguments: './caesar' and 'k', which given by the user. it works fine; but has one issue:

it encrypts "BARFOO" as "EDUIRR" using 3 as key which is correct
   encrypts "BaRFoo" as "FeVJss" using 4 as key which is correct

BUT it does not encrypt "barfoo" as "onesbb" using 65 as key, it encrypts it as "oonneess|bb|bb" .

Please notice the punctuation; the caps and so on.

See the problem here? it also does this for other random words; it repeats letters. Help me....

PS: I am extremely new to programming, as you can see in my code, so please try to explain in english!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
string s;
//int d;
int c;
int a;
if(argc != 2)
{   
    printf("Please run with a command line argument.");
    return 1;
}
else
{
    s = GetString();
}
int k = atoi(argv[1]);

for(int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)
    {
       a = s[i];
       if(a<'A'||a>'z')
       {
           printf(" ");
       }
       else
       {
           if(a>='A'&&a<='Z')
           {
               c = a+k;
               while(c>'Z')
               {
                   c = 'A'+(c-'Z')-1;
                   printf("%c", c);
               }

               if(c<='Z')
               {
                   printf("%c", c);
               }
           }
           else if(a>-'a'&&a<='z')
           {
               c = a+k;
               while(c>'z')
               {
                   c = 'a'+(c-'z')-1;
                   printf("%c", c);
               }
               if(c<='z')
               {
                   printf("%c", c);
               }
           }
       }
    }
printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: What is this: a>-'a'

Comment: Help me.... sure!  Run your code under your debugger and step through the failing case.

Comment: You wrote "c = a+k;" what happens if k is 1000? if you pass the number of letters? You have the % operator use it.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to take `k%26` since it should wrap around the characters of alphabet.
That should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should try this way. Take the case of uppercase letters. First get the index from the letter 'A'.
`index = a - 'A';`

Then add the value in the variable `k` and get the remainder when divided with 26.

`modified_index = ( index + k ) % 26;`

Now to get the desired letter just add it with `'A'`.

`c = 'A' + modified_index;`

Only adding `k%26` will not help as that way `'z'` with increment 1 will be turned into `{` which is wrong.

Also, if you just add value in `k` with the letter denoted by variable `a` it might cross the limit of ASCII characters as Joulin mentioned.